# What's the meaning of "He's trade through and through"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here are the quotes from HBO's drama *Gentleman Jack* ：

> A-He makes carpets, John Abbott.
>
> B-Wool, yes, probably.
>
> A-Either way, **he's trade** through and through. You're going to have to put the tin lid on that one. Otherwise, I will.

The meanings of trade in Urbandic are all about gay people in the closet, but is it the actual meaning here?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't have to do with sexual orientation. It means he's in the merchant class--works a trade--and from the context, the speaker is looking down on him because of it, presumably because they're of a higher social status.

Compare [this line](https://www.pemberley.com/janeinfo/ppv2n25.html#mrgardiner7) from *Pride and Prejudice*, set in roughly the same time period:

> "Mr. Gardiner was a sensible, gentlemanlike man... The Netherfield ladies*  would have had difficulty in believing that **a man who lived by trade**, and within view of his own warehouses, could have been so well bred and agreeable."

*the "Netherfield ladies" are social climbers who aspire to be part of the landed or titled class.

[To quote from the same website](https://www.pemberley.com/janeinfo/pptopics.html#trade): "One thing that may not be obvious is that it is always more "genteel" to be a rural land-owner than to be actively involved in commerce, no matter how much money you're making in business (**thus "trade", or business, can be a disparaging word**). This is why Mr. Gardiner is looked down upon."